# MVC using IEnumerable<Model> with Razor is null after post to controller

Tags: post, model-view-controller, model

My Model

```
public class ActivityModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nick { get; set; }
    public String TripName { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public TimeSpan? FromTime { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public TimeSpan? ToTime { get; set; }
    public String FromPlace { get; set; }
    public String ToPlace { get; set; }
    public String activityType { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public String Weather { get; set; }
    public int Difficulty { get; set; }
    public bool Reviewed { get; set; }
}
```

My View row looks like this

```
@model IList<ActivityModel>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    if (!(bool)Model[i].Reviewed)
    {
        <tr>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Accept", "Overview", FormMethod.Post, new { activityModel = Model }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Timestamp)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Timestamp)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Nick)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Nick)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].TripName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].TripName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].FromTime)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].FromTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].FromPlace)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].FromPlace)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].ToTime)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].ToTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].ToPlace)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].ToPlace)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Difficulty, new { id = "Difficulty" })
                    <--!@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Difficulty)--!>
                    <div style="visibility:hidden">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Reviewed)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].activityType)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Weather)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="btn_accept" value="Accept" />
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
     }
}
```

And my Controller is this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<ActivityModel> activities_web = new List<ActivityModel>();    
    //someLogicForFilling
    return View(activities_web);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult Accept(ActivityModel activityModel)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And the problem is that in ActionResult Accept is ActivityModel always NULL empty 0 ...
I really spent whole day on it for now and I don't know where is the problem i tried almost 20 solutions and nothing worked for me..

Rendering the page and showing all values is OK but when I try to POST them like nothing is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Model binding will work when the posted data matches with the property structure of the class you are using as your HttpPost action method parameter.

Your current view code is generating HTML code like this

```
<input name="[0].Id" type="hidden" value="101">
<input name="[1].Id" type="hidden" value="202">
```

Assuming you have 2 items in the collection you are passing to the view.

You can see that the `name` attribute value is `[0].Id` and `[1].Id`. But your `Accept` action method's parameter is a single `ActivityModel` object and the property names are like `Id`, `FromPlace` etc. For model binding to work, the names of your input and the property name should match.

You can rewrite your view code to generate the correct `name` attribute value for your hidden inputs. You may simply use the pure HTML code to create the hidden input and set the value from your model item or use the `Html.HiddenFor` helper method.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(a => a.Reviewed == false))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="FromPlace" value="@item.FromPlace" />
    @Html.Hidden("ToPlace", item.ToPlace)
    @Html.Hidden(nameof(ActivityModel.Id), item.Id)
}
```

Here is the full code (excluded some properties to save space).

```
@model IList<ActivityModel>
<table class="table table-striped">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(a => a.Reviewed == false))
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Accept", "Process", FormMethod.Post))
        {                   
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.FromPlace)
                    @Html.Hidden("FromPlace", item.FromPlace)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ToPlace)
                    @Html.Hidden("ToPlace", item.ToPlace)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Hidden(nameof(ActivityModel.Id),item.Id)
                    <input type="submit" name="btn_accept" value="Accept" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

But ideally, if you are trying to update the status of a single entity /record, all you need is the `Id` (primary key) of that record. that means, you really do not need all the properties populated. In that case, you need the hidden input element for the `Id` property value. You can always query the db to get the full entity using this `Id` if needed. ( Never trust data coming from client)

Comment: Yes this is it, the names are incorrectly created but why if i am using helpers i thought that it will create it right..why to use them if they are doing this mismatch of names?

Comment: Because you were creating inside a loop. The names it created are correct, if you want to do model binding to a  list of `ActivityModel` ( For example, if you want to do a edit on a bunch of records and submit them together. You will use `List<ActivityModel>` as your http post action method parameter and model binding will work fine.